# Send bitmap file in an HTTP response without using any libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, httpresponse, bmp

I want to send a bitmap file in an HTTP response, but I have no idea how to do it; I tried different ways but all failed. Only text can be sent, I just want to know where to begin. This is related code

```
client_connection.sendall("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
         +"Content-Type: image/bmp\n"
         +"Content-Lenth:%d"%size
         +"\n"
         +arr)
```

What to pass in place of `arr`? I am writing the bitmap into a `test.bmp` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong end-of-line-markers, and you have many typos. `arr` is the contents of your file:

```
with open('test.bmp', 'rb') as bmp:
    arr = bmp.read()
client_connection.sendall("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
     + "Content-Type: image/bmp\r\n"
     + "Content-Length: %d\r\n" % len(arr)
     + "\r\n"
     + arr)
```